# Choosing the primary key

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key, entity-attribute-value

I'm doing a project where i have to make a site almost like wikipedia, but while making the database i've stumbled across a problem.

I can't seem to figure out what my primary key should be. I tried my best to illustrate my table structure below, so you can see the problem.

```
name            | type        | content   |
--------------------------------------
John Doe        | overview    | some text |
----------------------------------------
John Doe        | background  | some text |
----------------------------------------
John Doe        | height      | some text |
----------------------------------------
Fred Flintstone | overview    | some text |
---------------------------------------
Fred Flintstone | background  | some text |
```

I dont think it would make sense to just make an id column, and auto increment it, as each record is useless alone.

What do you think? is a primary key needed? If so what should it be?

Comment: The possible values of 'type' form a finite set that is unlikely to change frequently? If so, I would reconsider removing 'type' as a column and having separate columns for 'overview', 'background' etc.

Comment: You almost certainly need some normalisation here.

Answer (score 4):

I would certainly go for an `Auto Increment` `primary ID`. That's what its for, it makes it easier to maintain and update the table, and also a lot easier to link to other tables in a relational setup.

There is also the matter of performance when looking up records.

To sum up:

> - Maintaining **relations** between tables
> - **Performance** when looking up records.
> - **Easier** to write update and delete queries when changing the content

See: http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/reasons-to-use-auto_increment-columns-on-innodb

Comment: Even though this isn't tagged SQL server, you are almost right when it comes to MySQL. Only InnoDB uses clustered primary key, other engines (like MyISAM) don't, and some support multiple clustered keys. In regards to the question itself, your answer is the best - auto_increment does yield best performance with InnoDB engine and it's the best choice for PK since PK's job is to make the row uniquely identifiable. A sequential integer does that job the best. +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the link. Fits the bill better I think, though less detailed. Does anyone know a better one.

Comment: `Performance when looking up records.` - are you assuming that the record will be looked up by ID?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create an id column as primary key and create one more table that will map the records like overview, background, height

```
id overview  background height 
1      1           3         5
```

though this type of schema is not fully normalize. other wise you can make different tables for overview, background and height and then create a relation table like above for them.

Answer (score 1):

Before you do any more work, take a look at [mediawiki.org](http://www.mediawiki.org/).

In your sample data, {name, type} uniquely identifies each row. But your sample data isn't representative.  Names aren't unique in the real world, so you probably need some other way to identify people.  Just adding an autoincrementing ID number as the primary key won't work, because it allows nonsense like this.

```
id  | name            | type        | content   |
--------------------------------------
1   | John Doe        | overview    | some text |
2   | John Doe        | overview    | some text |
3   | John Doe        | overview    | some text |
4   | John Doe        | overview    | some text |
```

How many distinct people are there? (There are 3. The John Does with id numbers 1 and 3 are the same person.)  A UNIQUE constraint on {name, type} won't help, either, because that would allow only one person named "John Doe" in the database.

So what else do you know that you can use to identify people?  Email address? (Don't look for a magic bullet here. There isn't one. Even email addresses can be shared. You're just looking for something better than "name".)